# Codeigniter 4 index.php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a question regarding CodeIgniter4..
Once copied all content from the folder, going to:

```
http://localhost/project-name/
```

It brings me to:
[This root page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfZgc.png)

My question is, how can i point:

```
http://localhost/project-name/ to http://localhost/project-name/public/index.php
```

Comment: You need to point your virtual host to look in the 'public' folder.

Comment: I'm wondering how to do it. I'm trying to learn php with codeigniter..

Comment: Are you using WAMP/ LAMPP or MAMP?

Comment: WAMP... I have this .htaccess in public folder https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/develop/public/.htaccess

Answer (score 0):

First make a local host like

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@projectName
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp7/htdocs/projectName"
    ServerName projectName.local
    ServerAlias projectName.local
    ErrorLog "C:/xampp7/htdocs/school/projectName.local-error.log"
    CustomLog "C:/xampp7/htdocs/school/projectName.local-access.log" combined
</VirtualHost>
```

and define the host too like the server name in the host file and point the folder you want to hit

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that when I try to point all my url to public/index.php in my project it return error 404 based on it can't find my controller after rewriting my .htaccess to point to public/index.php in my project root directory.

This is how I solved my problem =>

I move the index.php and the default .htaccess to my project root directory then I edit the index.php to locate my app directory

E.g

index.php Default find this line

```php
// This is the line that might need to be changed, depending on your folder structure.
$pathsPath = FCPATH . '../app/Config/Paths.php';
```

Change it to

```php
// This is the line that might need to be changed, depending on your folder structure.
$pathsPath = FCPATH . './app/Config/Paths.php';
```

I hope this work for you